# Drupal - Ubercart - USPS Shipping price-per-unit

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

This is sort of a last resort for me. I've posted a few things over at ubercart.org and haven't heard back anything, so I figured I would ask here. In any event, I'm running drupal 6 with the latest dev release of ubercart (upgraded from 2.4). I'm using the USPS shipping module, but it doesn't seem as if the amount of products added to the cart affects the shipping cost. For example, if I add 1 of product 1 to the cart, the shipping is $5.20. If I had 1000 of product 1 to the cart, it's still $5.20. I tried scouring the ubercart.org forums and google, I found some posts, but they were from 2008 and said that changes in regards to this have been since committed, so I'm at a loss.

Can anyone help me? Or point me to a thread that I may have missed?
Thanks a lot in advance!